# Assistance with IF Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops, count

I need some assistance with my tsql , I have knowledge of sql but mainly just querying tables and im finding tsql and loops quite difficult to finish off.
I have hit a sticking point with my IF STATEMENT. 
As you can see I have wrote the loop and attempted some debugging and the code is correct so far.

In the Else section
I need to check if it’s the first time through the loop using @firstloop and then copy all data , its mainly the loop that I’m having problems with and could do with help on getting a starting point.

I am using cursors but have been told it won’t affect performance because it’s not doing too much work and I would appreciate any help with the problem.I have also been told that some sections are Hard coded such as Production2 which should be @Source_Database_Name.

```
 declare @Source_Database_Name varchar(255) = 'Production2';
declare @Destination_Database_Name varchar(255) = 'c365online_script1';

declare @Company_Id int = 1 --declare a companyid 

CREATE TABLE #CompanyID (ID bigint)

INSERT INTO #CompanyID(ID)
    VALUES('15')


--FIRST CURSOR LOOP THROUGH THIS TABLE
CREATE TABLE #TableList (
    processorder int,
    tablename NVARCHAR(100)
    )
INSERT INTO #TableList (processorder, tablename )
VALUES
(1, 'tProperty');

DECLARE @firstLoop BIT
--SET @firstLoop = true
DECLARE @Counter INT  -- counting variable

----------- Cursor specific code starts here ------------
-- company cursor
declare copyCompanyDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
SELECT ID from #CompanyID;

open copyCompanyDataCursor
fetch next from copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        declare @processorder int;
        declare @tablename varchar(500);
        -- table cursor

        declare copyTableDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
        SELECT processorder,tablename from #TableList order by processorder;

        open copyTableDataCursor
        fetch next from copyTableDataCursor into @processorder, @tablename;

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1].[dbo].[tCompany] ON

            -- Does the table have a companyID column? if statement checking for company id
            IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM Production2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE COLUMN_NAME='CompanyID' and TABLE_NAME=@tablename)
            BEGIN
                declare @debug varchar(max)             
                SET @debug = 'INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + CAST(@Company_Id as varchar(10))
                print @debug
                --EXEC(@debug)
                --EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id )

            END
            ELSE
            -- if no check if this is the first time through company loop and copy all data- if @firstloop company exists look at information schema
            BEGIN 
                    Print 'No'
            END 
            -- if yes then copy data based on companyID in cursor  



                    --EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename )
                    -- company logic


            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1].[dbo].[tCompany] OFF

            FETCH NEXT FROM copyTableDataCursor into @processorder,@tablename;
        END

        close copyTableDataCursor;

        Deallocate copyTableDataCursor;
```

Comment: What problem are you facing. What issue are u hitting with else ? any error ?

Comment: No error I just want a starting point on checking if its the first time gone through loop using @firstloop

Comment: Why are you using cursors to loop? Have you tried a purely set-based solution?

Comment: I have been told to use cursors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using the cursor. To answer your question of "checking if its the first time gone through loop" then below is the soullution for this.

Declare a variable above  "while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0" Line.
somethign like "Firsttime =  0 "

Under IF , "Firsttime =  1 " Which means this is not first time.

In ELSE , check 
          ---> if "Firsttime =  0 " Then it mean first time 
          ---> if "Firsttime =  1 " Then it mean its not first time